# Math mode in tabular with siunitx

Tags: tables, math-mode, siunitx

My file compiled with siunitx 2 (TexLive 2020) but breaks with 3 (TexLive 2021). I can't find useful info in the [upgrade section](https://mirror-hk.koddos.net/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/siunitx/siunitx.pdf) of the manual.

MWE: https://www.overleaf.com/read/wmgnzhqhbfpy

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}


\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \begin{tabular}{ r S[table-format=2.3] }
        \(k\)  &  \(x_1^{(k)}\) \\
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You forgot a pair of braces in the second column, like this `{\(x_1^{(k)}\)}`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put curly braces around the material which is not numeric but should show up in an `S` type column.

So use the following instead (works in both v2 and v3):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}


\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ r S[table-format=2.3] }
  \(k\)  &  {\(x_1^{(k)}\)} \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: So I was wrong all along? Why didn't siunitx 2 complain about this?

Comment: And why does `\(k\)` not need this?

Comment: @MinhNghĩa `\(k\)` is not in an `S`-column

Comment: Ughhh... rookie mistake on me :)

Comment: @MinhNghĩa presumably because v2 did protect against this. But one big reason for the rewrite (afaik) was to speed `siunitx` up, so some processing overhead was removed.